# [react-test-renderer]: Why in tests after run "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

So, I use renderer from 'react-test-renderer' for snapshots, but in console after run I have a warning:
**Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.**

In component, I don't use map for rendering list of components

````
    Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.

      at printWarning (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:68:30)
      at error (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:44:5)
      at warnForMissingKey (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:4441:5)
      at warnOnInvalidKey (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:4908:11)
      at reconcileChildrenIterator (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:5129:23)
      at reconcileChildFibers (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:5435:14)
      at reconcileChildren (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7991:28)```
````

Comment: React makes a virtual dom and it uses keys, which the user never sees, to know which list item is which. That way, it knows which list item to update, instead of updating the entire list on every render. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html. It's very easy to add keys `<ul>array.map((stuff, index) => <li key={index} {...stuff}>item</li></ul>`. I've only seen that error when mapping, but it's possible the error is there in other situations.

Comment: You should [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have the same problem, and still couldn't find a solution to it. did you find, @Denys ?

Comment: My problem was that I was using shallow from enzyme with renderer from react-test-renderer, like this:
`import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
const component = (props) => shallow(<PaymentDescription />);
const wrapper = renderer.create(component).toJSON();
expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();`

It helped me without shallow:
`const wrapper = renderer.create(<PaymentDescription />).toJSON();
expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();`

@JeanMichell